# Erro variavel char C Visual Studio

Tags: c, char

Estou tendo problemas ao usar o scanf_s em uma variavel tipo char somente no visual studio.
Quando chega na linha do scanf_s o programa para e me traz o seguinte erro:

> Exception thrown at 0x7893E63C (ucrtbased.dll) in exercicio4.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00F00000.

Isso só acontece no Visual studio, quando uso compiladores on line não ocorre

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char a[25];

    printf("Digite seu primeiro nome: ");
    scanf_s("%s", a);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tente executar como administrador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `scanf_s` possui um terceiro parâmetro, opcional, que representa o tamanho do buffer em caracteres. Acredito que esse seja o problema que ocorre no seu caso (a não especificação desse parâmetro), já que o problema é "violação de acesso de escrita".

Citando [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019):

> O tamanho do buffer em caracteres é passado como um parâmetro
>   adicional. Ele segue imediatamente o ponteiro para o buffer ou a
>   variável. Por exemplo, se você estiver lendo uma cadeia de caracteres,
>   o tamanho do buffer dessa cadeia de caracteres será passado da
>   seguinte maneira:
>
> ```
> char s[10];
> scanf_s("%9s", s, (unsigned)_countof(s)); // buffer size is 10, width specification
> ```

No seu caso, experimente:

`scanf_s("%s", a, (unsigned)_countof(a));`

ou

`scanf_s("%24s", a, (unsigned)_countof(a));`

Comment: realmente a primeira solução dada resolveu meu problema muito obrigado!